# Shadow effect on both side of a div

Tags: html, css

I wish to add a gradient image to both sides of my main div on homepage.

My image looks like this

[image: Gradient_Image]

Can anyone help me in this ? I thought of having a div outside the main with background image as this, but that didnt work.

Comment: If you try this on jsFiddle, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: ok, I will give u the link for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/semencov/A5b6g/

Replace background image for `.wrapper .inner` to correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If the div is of fixed size you can have a background image of same size with repeat-y

Comment: if you take a closer look you'll see the top of the background-image is not quite continuous, so this could be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your HTML/CSS nor image, you can go to [this live site](http://www.savvysource.com) and look at the `div#nss_outer_page`. It has the exact style you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

- Try css3 Shadows
- Try a fixed with Background-image in combination with a padding
- There are a few techniques out there like http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssdropshadows/ or just google it

Comment: do not use the image, but css3 shadows